# Should I drain my winterized pool after a large rainstorm?

Tags: water, pool

I just installed a safety/mesh winter cover and closed my pool.  Over the past month we've had a few big rain storms so the water level is already at the skimmer.  Winter hasn't even arrived yet and I'm worried that it will overflow.

Should take the corner off and drain the water again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to drain, perhaps multiple times depending on the amount of rain/snow you get.  I bought a Wayne PC4 pump to remove excess water (Caveat: I made a mistake and used it with my saltwater pool, so it's rusting).

Your mesh cover manual will provide guidance on the height of your cover relative to the water level.  If you drain too much, the mesh cover can tear under heavy snow.  I have a Meyco and it says about 18".  But in my case, I keep the pool at about 13" below the level of the mesh covers, which gives me 5" of clearance on my skimmers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an inground pool, when you closed the pool you likely plugged the drains in your skimmers so there is no need to drain the pool to specifically protect the skimmers. Generally, if you live in an area where the pool will likely freeze over the winter you should keep the water level below the level of the tiles so they do not crack from the freeze.
Meyco covers hold up pretty well - I just bought a new one after 18 years on the old one.